# Typescript Partial params in constructor and access in extended class

Tags: typescript

How can I achieve this:

```
export class Base
{
    constructor(public defaultValues: Partial<Base>)
    {
        if (defaultValues)
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(defaultValues))
                this[key] = value;
    }
}

export class Extended extends Base
{
    public prop1: boolean;

    public method1()
    {
        //prop1 does not exists, because defaultValues are Base not Extended
        this.defaultValues.prop1;     //!!!! ERROR Property 'prop1' does not exists on type 'Partial<Base>'.
    }
}
```

I need to set some default values to class itself and store it in variable, so I can access defaultValues later.

**Edited:**
I also try:

```
class Base<T extends Base = any> {
    constructor(public defaultValues: Partial<T>) {

    }
}

class Extended extends Base<Extended> {
    public prop1: boolean;

    public method1() {
        this.defaultValues.prop1;
    }
}
```

But got error:

[image]

and this, but now I get error that

> T[keyof T] is not accessible to this[keyof t]

:

```
export class Base<T extends Base<T>>
{
    constructor(public defaultValues: T)
    {
        if (defaultValues)
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(defaultValues))
                this[key] = value;  //!!!!! ERROR
    }
}

export class Extended extends Base<Extended>
{
    public prop1: boolean;

    public method1()
    {        
        this.defaultValues.prop1; 
    }
}
```

Error with default parameters:[image]

**Edited 3:**
After installing [VS 15.3 (VS 2017 update 2)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes#typescript) and Typescript SDK 2.3 and after choosing Typescript 2.3 in Intellisense  for VS 2017 I made some progress.
Have just a little tiny problem:[image]

Comment: Are you using the `--noImplicitAny` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Base` doesn't have a member called `prop1`, `Extended` does.
You can make `Base` generic:

```
class Base<T extends Base = any> {
    constructor(public defaultValues: Partial<T>) {
        ...
    }
}

class Extended extends Base<Extended> {
    public prop1: boolean;

    public method1() {
        this.defaultValues.prop1;
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

Before typescript 2.3 (because of [Generic parameter defaults](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-parameter-defaults)) you need to do:

```
class Base<T extends Base<any>> {
    constructor(public defaultValues: Partial<T>) {

    }
}
```

---

#### 2nd edit

If you're using the `noImplicitAny` flag then you need to do this:

```
class Base<T extends Base<any>> {
    constructor(public defaultValues: T) {
        if (defaultValues) {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(defaultValues)) {
                this[key as keyof this] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The difference being `this[key as keyof this] = value;`

Comment: It does not work. I get error and you can check it in my edited post.

Comment: [Generic parameter defaults](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-parameter-defaults) is a new feature in typescript 2.3

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: I upgraded to 2.3.4. I had a little mess with global typescript being old. But it does not work! Check my latest image. 
Thank you for trying.

Comment: Check if you are using a local version of tsc and that is updated.

Comment: Local is version 2.3.3 and global 2.3.4.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Hi, we are very close. Do you have any idea for error I have in Edited 3?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  Can you please reproduce your problem in playground so that we can avoid this ping pong?

Comment: I give up and added as any. Can't reproduce in playground and can not fix in my project.